Tengo un Bug con un componente tipo Plantilla

Hola bro, gracias por responder, lamentablemente, ya habia intentado el diferenciar por key, (no lo dije en la publi).. Sigue el mismo bug q reemplaza los valores

Este componente, lo hice tipo plantilla para poder reutilizar código, se trata de una Alarma de reloj, pero al momento de instanciar por ej 2 instancias, el valor de la ultima reemplaza a la primera:
import { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { IoAlarmOutline } from "react-icons/io5";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import getTime from "../../../../../JS/Logic/clock";
import toastiWarning from "../../../../../JS/Toastify/warning";
import toastiSuccess from "../../../../../JS/Toastify/success";
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import { IoAlarm } from "react-icons/io5";

function BaseAlarm({ numberOfClock, intervalRef, setIntervalRef,iconAlarm, setIconAlarm }) {
const inputTimeRef = useRef(null);
//const [intervalRef, setIntervalRef] = useState(null); // Estado para almacenar la 
referencia del intervalo
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    clearInterval(intervalRef); // Limpiar el intervalo al desmontar el componente
  };
 }, [intervalRef]);

return (
   <div>
      <button className="buttonAlarm" onClick={handleShow} key={numberOfClock}>
       //cambio de icono
      {iconAlarm === "empty" ? <IoAlarmOutline /> : <IoAlarm />}
      </button>

  <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
    <Modal.Header closeButton>
      <Modal.Title>Alarm {numberOfClock}</Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Body>
      <input type="time" ref={inputTimeRef} />
      <Button
        onClick={() =>
          getTimeFromUser(
            inputTimeRef,
            setIconAlarm,
            numberOfClock,
            setIntervalRef // Pasar la función para actualizar la referencia del intervalo
          )
        }
      >
        Save Changes
      </Button>
    </Modal.Body>
    <Modal.Footer>
      <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
        Close
      </Button>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
        Save Changes
      </Button>
    </Modal.Footer>
  </Modal>
  <ToastContainer />
</div>
   );
 }

   export default BaseAlarm;
  //Recoger el input del cliente, y compararlo con la hora de mi tiempo.
 const getTimeFromUser = (
       inputTimeRef,
       setIconAlarm,
       numberOfClock,
       setIntervalRef 
     ) => {
       let hourFromUser = parseInt(inputTimeRef.current.value.slice(0, 2));
       let minuteFromUser = parseInt(inputTimeRef.current.value.slice(3, 5));

       let restHour = hourFromUser - getTime().hours;
       let restMinute = minuteFromUser - getTime().minute;

   const tryet = setInterval(() => {
if (
  objectOfTime.hourObject === getTime().hours &&
  objectOfTime.minuteObject === getTime().minute
) {
  toastiSuccess("Tu turututu tururu xd");
  setIconAlarm("empty");
  clearInterval(tryet);
  return;
}
}, 1000);

 objectOfTime.id = numberOfClock;
 objectOfTime.hourObject = hourFromUser;
 objectOfTime.minuteObject = minuteFromUser;

 //En este if, trato de comparar el id guardado
if (objectOfTime.id === numberOfClock) {
objectOfTime.hourObject = hourFromUser;
objectOfTime.minuteObject = minuteFromUser;
}
toastiWarning(
`The alarm will sound in ${restHour} hours and ${restMinute} minutes from now`
 );
 setIconAlarm("full");

 setIntervalRef(tryet); // Actualizar la referencia del intervalo
};
 const objectOfTime = {
id: 0,
hourObject: "",
minuteObject: "",
};

Al momento de yo instanciar esta plantilla (con 2 ejemplos de alarmas) como está descrita abajo, pasandoles sus propios intervalos, y su propio icono
import { useState } from "react";
import BaseAlarm from "./BaseAlarm";
function Alarm1() {
 const [intervalRef1, setIntervalRef1] = useState(null);
 const [intervalRef2, setIntervalRef2] = useState(null);
 const [iconAlarm1, setIconAlarm1] = useState("empty");
 const [iconAlarm2, setIconAlarm2] = useState("empty");

return (
<>
  <BaseAlarm
    numberOfClock={1}
    intervalRef={intervalRef1}
    setIntervalRef={setIntervalRef1}
    iconAlarm={iconAlarm1}
    setIconAlarm={setIconAlarm1}
  />
  <BaseAlarm
    numberOfClock={2}
    intervalRef={intervalRef2}
    setIntervalRef={setIntervalRef2}
    iconAlarm={iconAlarm2}
    setIconAlarm={setIconAlarm2}
  />
</>
);
}

 export default Alarm1;

Agrego 2 alarmas, y al momento de activar la primera, y luego la segunda, esta ultima reemplaza el valor de tiempo del primero, y suenan las 2 alarmas juntas a la hora de la segunda.

Elimino mi primera respuesta y comento lo de key: Durante la reconciliación, React encuentra un componente BaseAlarm repetido en el mismo scope, destruye el primero y conserva el último, Para diferenciarlos se puede agregar la propiedad key con un valor único para cada componente BaseAlarm

Puede ser un problema de concurrency, describe más detalles de funcionamiento de getTimeFromUser así como baseAlarm para poder apoyarte, actualizo la respuesta con tu comentario.

@g.4 Hola brooo, un panita me recomendó agregar la funcion getTimeFromUser dentro del componente, y ahora si suena la alarma(el mensaje como alarma) a la hora debida de cada uno... Pero, sigue apareciendo el mensaje 2 veces en cada alarma, y debería de aparecer solo uno por cada alarma :), tu sabes cual es la diferencia entre q la función este adentro del componente y afuera?. Y como podría hacer para que muestre el mensaje una sola vez, y no imprima tantas veces (como recorriendo cada alarma).
